# Weirdness in views when grouping by a field, and a user has more than one entry in that field

Tags: 7, views

I have a view that shows users. Users are associated with an Area in the organization.  The view groups by Area (a vocabulary) and gives a list with nice area headings, with a list of Users inside it.  Unfortunately there is one executive in the organization that is also in charge of another Area, and he needs to appear in both places.  When I assign both areas to his account (entity reference field), we get the following (problematic user in bright blue):

[image]

What should happen, is that the blue user should appear once in the Executives area and once in the PMO area.  Instead as you can see, he appears twice in his own special Executives \n PMO area.  It would even be ok, if he only appeared in the Executives area here.  What can I change to get this view to be nice to me?

Comment: `When I assign both areas to his account` Are you using tax term reference for this? or ???

Comment: I had to go remind myself, looks like it is an entity reference.

Comment: so executives is a node of some content type?

Comment: No, sorry, I guess I still wasn't clear with that. Area is a vocabulary, so executive is a term, but the field is an entity reference.

Comment: Why is Executives shown twice? is that part of your problem?

Comment: Yeah, it seems that because the guy has both executive and pmo, he has his own heading with both in it. At least as far as I've gathered so far.

Comment: So you don't want any repeating headers, right? Executives and under that all the names, PMO and under that all the names?

Comment: Yes. And it is fine for me if that guy appears under both or just under the first one. It is a different view in which I need him to appear in a pmo list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42526/discussion-between-no-sssweat-and-ultrabob).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your hidden entity reference field's setting in Views, scroll down to *Multiple field settings* and **uncheck** *Display all values in the same row*.

When grouping, the content / user will get shown twice instead of what your screenshot shows.

Comment: Thank you!  I guess that option hadn't displayed before (I just recently allowed multiple values in that field), and it sounds like it should do the opposite of what it does.

Comment: And on deeper reflection I understand why that setting does what it does..

Comment: Cool. And yea that default setting catches a lot of people I'd say. If you get to a point where grouping doesn't provide enough functionality, https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view is very powerful. Another view as fields in views. It's just a bit slow if you have a dozens or hundreds of them.